# What does the form tag pass to the Code Behind

Tags: .net-core, primary-key

In an application I'm working on, users are allowed to add comments. However, I'm getting an error when the comment attempts to be saved to the database. The errors say...

> SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Comments' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
>
> DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

The database is supposed to auto-generate the primary key but for some reason, the comment model is assigning the `Comment.ID` (which is the primary key) to the current project ID (that is, `Submission.ID`) the user is commenting on. What needs to happen is the application should allow the DB to assign the primary key/`Comment.ID`.

Can someone tell me why the application is setting the primary key?

**View**

```
<form method="post" class="col-12">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Body" placeholder="Add Comment" />
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm my-2 float-right" />
    </form>
```

**Controller**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(int id)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return Page();

        // Adding values to fields automatically. These fields are not on the form for users to see and update.
        Comment.SubmissionID = Submission.ID;
        Comment.CreatedBy = "Andre";
        Comment.CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;
        _SubmissionContext.Comments.Add(Comment);

        await _SubmissionContext.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToPage("ProjectDetails", new { ID = id });
    }
```

**Model**

```
public class Comment
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int SubmissionID { get; set; }
    public Submission Submission { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "text")]
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:g}")]
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

}
```

**Migration Class**

```
namespace IST_Submission_Form.Migrations
{
[DbContext(typeof(SubmissionContext))]
partial class SubmissionContextModelSnapshot : ModelSnapshot
{
    protected override void BuildModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
#pragma warning disable 612, 618
        modelBuilder
            .HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "2.1.3-rtm-32065")
            .HasAnnotation("Relational:MaxIdentifierLength", 128)
            .HasAnnotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);

        modelBuilder.Entity("IST_Submission_Form.Models.Comment", b =>
            {
                b.Property<int>("ID")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                    .HasAnnotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);

                b.Property<string>("Body")
                    .HasColumnType("text");

                b.Property<DateTime>("CreatedAt");

                b.Property<string>("CreatedBy");

                b.Property<int>("SubmissionID");

                b.HasKey("ID");

                b.HasIndex("SubmissionID");

                b.ToTable("Comment");
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity("IST_Submission_Form.Models.Submission", b =>
            {
                b.Property<int>("ID")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                    .HasAnnotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);

                b.Property<string>("AssignedTo");

                b.Property<DateTime>("Date");

                b.Property<string>("DesiredCompletionDate")
                    .HasColumnName("Timeline");

                b.Property<string>("Email");

                b.Property<string>("Files");

                b.Property<string>("FirstName");

                b.Property<string>("Goal");

                b.Property<string>("LastName");

                b.Property<string>("Location");

                b.Property<string>("LoginID");

                b.Property<string>("ProjectDescription")
                    .HasColumnType("text");

                b.Property<int>("Status");

                b.Property<string>("Title");

                b.HasKey("ID");

                b.ToTable("Submissions");
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity("IST_Submission_Form.Models.Comment", b =>
            {
                b.HasOne("IST_Submission_Form.Models.Submission", "Submission")
                    .WithMany("Comments")
                    .HasForeignKey("SubmissionID")
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
            });
#pragma warning restore 612, 618
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I am not sure why. As I see you are using EntityFramework Code First right? If so, can you add the migration class?

Comment: I added it. I hope that's what you were asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I eventually just deleted the DB tables and migrations and went through the process of recreating them. I'm in production so it wasn't a big deal. The application works fine now even with the comments that I was trying to add.

I think the problem was due to the fact that I added another table to my DB context and didn't properly do a migration as I should have.

For the record, my code was right after all. The migrations were the issue.